# ng2-bootstrap cannot register alert, datepicker in angular2

Tags: angular, systemjs, ng2-bootstrap

I'm using angular2 and ng2-bootstrap.

In my module.ts, I have declared like this

```
import { Ng2BootstrapModule, AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
imports:      [ BrowserModule,
    ...,
    Ng2BootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    ... ]
```

In my component template I have declared like this:

test alert

My systemjs.config.js:

```
map:{
  ...,
  'moment': 'npm:moment',
  'ng2-bootstrap': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap',
  ...
},
packages: {
  ...,
  'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'ng2-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  ...
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

What's my missing. Please help me about that. I spent several hours to find solution, but could not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ng2BootstrapModule come from ng2-bootstrap which is declared in module.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you need datepicker and alert, please import them

```
import { DatepickerModule, AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
imports:      [ BrowserModule,
    ...,
    DatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
```

What could happen:
Angular requires import of modules used for rendering
in corresponding submodules

Comment: Finally I resolve myself. I had `AppModule.ts` is main, and `QuestionTagModule.ts` is sub module. I was missing import `AlertModule` in sub module file. I only import `Ng2BootstrapModule.forRoot()` in main module. 


That's my silly thing.

Thank guys anyway.

Comment: seems I need to rephrase this ` in corresponding submodules`

Comment: Please I can't understand you and I have the same problem. So I have to `import AlertModule.forRoot()` in appmodule and the same string `import AlertModule.forRoot()` in the module of the component I want to use? Why twice? if it's forRoot() it should be ok if I just import it in parent appmodule, right?